# About displaying posts from two or more blogs

Tags: php, blogs

I want to display posts of two or more blogs in my website now am using **magpierss-0.72** for fetching the posts and my code is

```
require_once('rss_fetch.inc');
    $url = 'http://rajs-creativeguys.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss'
    /*'http://raghuks.wordpress.com/feed/'*/;
    $rss = fetch_rss($url);
    foreach ($rss->items as $i => $item ) { 
        $title = strtoupper ($item['title']);
        $url   = $item['link'];
        $date = substr($item['pubdate'],0,26);
        //code to fetch only some text
        $desc = '';
        $max = 30;
        $arr = explode(' ', strip_tags($item['description']));
        $l = count($arr);
        if($l < $max) $max = $l;
        for($j=0;$j<$max;++$j) {
            $desc .= $arr[$j] . ' ';
        }
        $desc .= '.....';
        echo "<div class=\"blog\"><a target=\"_blank\" href=$url><h1>$title</h1>$desc<br/><br/>DATED : $date <br/><br/></a></div> ";
        if($i == 3) break; 
    }
```

Here i can specify only one url of feeds and can fetch but now i want to display posts of two or more blogs Please give me the solution

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Just use an array and throw in another foreach:

```
<?php
require_once('rss_fetch.inc');

$urls = array(
'http://rajs-creativeguys.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss',
' more urls ... ',
);

foreach($urls as $url) {
    /*'http://raghuks.wordpress.com/feed/'*/;
    $rss = fetch_rss($url);
    foreach ($rss->items as $i => $item ) { 
        $title = strtoupper ($item['title']);
        $url   = $item['link'];
        $date = substr($item['pubdate'],0,26);

        //code to fetch only some text
        $desc = '';
        $max = 30;
        $arr = explode(' ', strip_tags($item['description']));
        $l = count($arr);
        if($l < $max) $max = $l;
        for($j=0;$j<$max;++$j)
        {
            $desc .= $arr[$j] . ' ';
        }
        $desc .= '.....';
        echo "<div class=\"blog\"><a target=\"_blank\" href=$url><h1>$title</h1>$desc<br/><br/>DATED : $date <br/><br/></a></div> ";
        if($i == 3) break; 
    }
}
```